# Create a layout with two rezisable columns without javascript

Tags: html, css

With the legacy frameset, you could create two user-resizable panels like so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HTML Frames</title>
</head>

<frameset cols="10%,80%">
    <frame name="left" src="left.html" />
    <frame name="right" src="right.html" />

    <noframes>
        <body>Your browser does not support frames.</body>
    </noframes>

</frameset>
</html>
```

I want to replace these "frames" with two regular elements, with inline content. The question is about layout, not how to include a different resource (which is an iframe). Preferably, the solution should work with CSS only and not require any javascript. As a bonus, it should change to rows if browser window aspect ration goes from wide to tall.

Comment: search and try CSS Grid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout, tuto here https://www.quackit.com/css/grid/tutorial/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Flexbox layout to put two resizable panes next to each other. Without JavaScript, you will have to drag from the pane's corner, though.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.frameset {
  height: 100vh;
  background: beige;
  display: flex;
}

.frame {
  min-width: min-content;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.frame.left {
  flex: 0 1 auto;
  resize: horizontal;
}

.frame.right {
  border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="frameset">
  <div class="frame left">Content on the left.</div>
  <div class="frame right">Stuff on the right.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do I control the initial position of the division? It appears to default to full left, but I would like an initial division of 50/50